# UTC time convert

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, utc

I want to display a certain time on my page, NOT the local time of the visitor, but the timezone where I am at the moment.
I use this code I found on plus2net:

```
function display_ct7() {
var x = new Date()
var ampm = x.getHours( ) >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am';
hours = x.getHours( ) % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12;
hours=hours.toString().length==1? 0+hours.toString() : hours;

var minutes=x.getMinutes().toString()
minutes=minutes.length==1 ? 0+minutes : minutes;

var seconds=x.getSeconds().toString()
seconds=seconds.length==1 ? 0+seconds : seconds;

var x1=hours + ":" +  minutes + ":" +  seconds + " " + ampm;
document.getElementById('ct7').innerHTML = x1;
display_c7();
 }
 function display_c7(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct7()',refresh)
}
display_c7()
```

It shows now the time in Germany (UTC +2h).
And it works but it has some errors in the code, says dreamweaver. Due to the fact that I am not used to js, can someone maybe help me to "clean" this code? Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`Date.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) for this purpose. You can pass any [`IANA timezone`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you wish and the output will be displayed in this zone.

For Germany, this will be 'Europe/Berlin'.

In the below code, we'll display the user's local time if no timezone is passed.

You can add one or more of these clocks easily.

```js
// If timeZone is not passed we'll return local time...
function getTime(timeZone) {
    let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone });
    // Ensure lower case and leading zero..
    return time.toLowerCase().padStart(11, '0');
}

function displayClockInElement(elementId, timeZone) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = getTime(timeZone);
}
 
function startClock(refreshRate, elementId, timeZone) {
    displayClockInElement(elementId, timeZone);
    setInterval(displayClockInElement, refreshRate, elementId, timeZone)
}

startClock(1000, 'local');
startClock(1000, 'de', 'Europe/Berlin');
startClock(1000, 'utc', 'UTC');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr><th>Timezone</th><th>Time</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>Local</td><td id='local'></td></tr>
  <tr><td>UTC</td><td id='utc'></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Berlin</td><td id='de'></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```